# HTML5 Input Datepicker: Disable reset date option

Tags: html, input, datepicker

Is there a way which allows me to disable the date reset button "x" which sets the date to dd/mm/yyyy (see attached)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pseudo-elements, from [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/):

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
::-webkit-inner-spin-button
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `required` attribute.

```
<input type=date required>
```

Comment: faster than adding css rules

Answer (score 2):

The Html date input is not supported by every browser.
The "x" you want to disable is specific to google chrome.

Like [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286670/3170216) say, i think the jQuery datepicker is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) from jQuery is a better choice.

Comment: @Dav  You are very welcome. Next time, you could try jQuery. It is very helpful.